# Trouble beating the huge guard in “Gone Missing” level

Tags: tomb-raider-2013

[image: screenshot of "huge guard"]

This guy is the one I’m struggling with. I’m playing on a Mac btw. I can get him weakened okay but then I see the kill symbol over his head - and from walkthroughs I’ve looked at, I need to use a melee attack to finish him off. The problem is when I run over to him and press <kbd>F</kbd> (for melee) it still only lets me aim my weapons, not use them to attack melee style. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you melee other random normal enemies?  Did you accidentally unbind or change your melee attack?

Answer (score 3):

You must have set the key F from melee to aiming that's why Lara isn't meleeing and is aiming towards the tall fellow. Go to setting and then go to button mapping and then map the melee to F key. You can also map 2 keys per function in TR 2013 so you might have F for both melee and aiming so you'll have to unbind F from aiming.

Answer (score -1):

I had the exact same issue, the problem I was facing was the exclamation mark was supposed to appear when the guard is wounded, it didn't happen when I was playing in FHD resolution (1920x1080). When i lowered the resolution to 800x600, the exclamation mark started appearing properly.

If you don't want to lower the resolution, then some others on the steam community has suggested to time the attack , you can count 1-2-3-4 and then use the melee attack.

BTW, I faced the same issue in the boss level as well, lowering the resolution did the trick there as well.

Comment: This is not addressing the OP's problem ("but then I see the kill symbol over his head").

Comment: @Joachim have you played this game at this exact resolution? I had the exact same problem, I reached the thread by searching this problem. This is a known bug in the game.

Comment: But the OP can see the kill symbol (hence the quotation), so this is not applicable to their situation. If your information can help others, you can always create a new question and answer it yourself using this solution.